# Transposing a text file row into columns using VBScripting

Tags: vbscript

I currently have a text file that looks like this

[image]

I need to be able to create a VBScript file that will use FileSystemObject to change the rows into columns and output the data into an html table like below

[image]

I am having a difficult time finding a method for transposing.  I am new to VBscripting, I assume that I can still use the CreateTextFile method for HTML?

```
Dim fso, MyFile
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set MyFile = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\User.mdm\Desktop\PracticeTest\table.html", True)
MyFile.WriteLine(?)
MyFile.Close
```

Comment: Hint: read the text file, fill a 2D array, [transpose it](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Matrix_transposition#VBScript), write html file.

Comment: Hint #2: instead of a 2D array which is indexed as `array2D( row, column)` would be simpler to fill a 1D array of 1D arrays which would be indexed as `array1x1( row)( column)`. In any case, split your task into pieces of code that do a certain (simpler) sub-tasks (as I advised previously; just a kind of [modular programming](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_programming)).

Comment: Instead of asking, a bit searching would have showed you a nearly perfect template here in SO. [VBscript - Transpose CSV File](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22644689/6811411)  I didn't test but IMO all you have to change is path and `tmp = Split(row, ",")` to `tmp = Split(row, "|")`

Comment: Thanks guys for the help/direction.  I just need to work on figuring out the html piece